# How do I override the search template in a plugin?

Tags: templates, hooks, search

How do I override the search template i.e. used inside a theme with a custom search page inside a plugin? Please point our any relevant action/filter hooks which can be used to do this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `template_include` filter hook

```
add_filter('template_include','my_custom_search_template');

function my_custom_search_template($template){
    global $wp_query;
    if (!$wp_query->is_search)
        return $template;
    
    return dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/my_search_template.php';

} /*UPDATE: there was a missing ";" after $template*/
```

Comment: Missing semicolon (;) after return $template

Answer (score 0):

If i read your question correctly then it has been answered on [**stackoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647604/wp-use-file-in-plugin-directory-as-custom-page-template). The link covers creating custom page templates upon plugin activation and also covers template redirect hook.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the search form with a shortcode.

```
function my_custom_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = do_shortcode('[your_custom_search_form]');
    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'my_custom_search_form', 40 );
```